# access() says file exists but fopen() says it does not

Tags: c, git, fopen

I have a c program that is trying to read in a file. Using the `access()` command it says the file is there but `fopen()` returns NULL and errno says the file does not exist.

A truncated snippet of code:

```
  FILE *fp;
  char *filename = strdup(git_dir);
  strcat(filename, "/HEAD");

  printf(git_dir);
  printf(":");
  printf(filename);
  printf(":");

  if (access(filename, F_OK)) {
    printf("Y U NO OPEN:");
  }

  fp = fopen(filename, "r");
  if (fp == NULL) {
    printf(strerror(errno));
    return;
  }
```

As you might tell from the code, this is trying to open the .git/HEADS file of a git repository. The particular repository this is failing on was cloned into a subdir of another repository and then added as a submodule. I do not have problems that were cloned by running the `git submodule update` command.

The above code does not print "Y U NO OPEN:" but it does print out the `strerror()`. I printed the filename to the screen and opened the file with `less` and it opens fine. This program is generating my zsh prompt, so I imagine it is being run by my user, and the permissions on the file are

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 ben users   23 Jun 30 13:32 HEAD
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What printf(strerror(errno)) prints?

Comment: @AlexG.P.: You can use `perror("ERROR")` instead of.

Comment: The error printed was something to the effect of "file does not exist"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this:

```
char *filename = strdup(git_dir);
strcat(filename, "/HEAD");
```

You're appending the string "/HEAD" to filename, but filename only has room for the content of `git_dir`. Thus you're writing past the buffer, overwriting memory, and possibly causing havoc, and all kinds of unpredictable behavior can occur.

Do this instead:

```
char *filename = malloc(strlen(git_dir) + 6); //length of /HEAD + null terminator
strcpy(filename, git_dir);
strcat(filename, "/HEAD");
```

Keep in mind that stdout is normally line-buffered as well. This means that if you do `printf("Y U NO OPEN:");` , you might not see the output immediately. Print a newline, \n, to flush the output.

Comment: `perror()` is handy for writing the `errno` value with a newline.

Comment: This was the problem! Curious that there were only a couple examples that I found where the old code didn't work (and they both happened to be submodules that I cloned before adding them as submodules). Thanks for the answer!